Vectorize selecting regions from image using pytorch
I have an image in torch of size (H, W). I want to select a number of square regions and concatenate these regions. The regions are square and equally sized but in different locations. See the example code below for the for loop version:
import torch

image = torch.arange(5*5).reshape(5, 5)

region_size = 2
xmin = torch.tensor([0,1,2])
xmax = xmin + region_size
ymin = torch.tensor([0,0,0])
ymax = ymin + region_size
num_regions = xmin.shape[0]

output = torch.zeros(xmin.shape[0], 2, 2)

for i in range(xmin.shape[0]):
    region = image[xmin[i] : xmax[i], ymin[i] : ymax[i]]
    output[i,...] = region

>>>image
>>>tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
>>>output
>>>tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
            [ 5.,  6.]],

           [[ 5.,  6.],
            [10., 11.]],

           [[10., 11.],
            [15., 16.]]])

Problem
Number of regions is very large in practice and the for loop is too slow
Tried
My initial plan was to expand the image array to the number of regions and then create a mask layer for each region and use this to extract the values:
image.unsqueeze(0).expand((num_regions, -1, -1))
mask = torch.zeros_like(image)
mask = ...
values = image[mask==1]

But I am getting stuck on how to create the mask efficiently. Some help on this or any other approach would be much appreciated :)

Creating the mask is also going to need a loop. And then you’re just adding a large array for nothing. Did you consider using Numba to JIT-compile the loop?

I have not yet, I will try it and time the difference
